# How to convert 2-dimensional data into 3-D (Non-linear data)?

Tags: python, classification, knn, multiclass-classification, type-2-dimension

I have created synthetic data like ,

```py
X, Y = make_classification(n_features=2,n_samples=100, n_redundant=0, n_informative=1,
                                 n_clusters_per_class=1, class_sep=0.001,weights= [0.8,0.2] ,n_classes=2 ,random_state=42)

df = CreateDataFrame(X,Y,['X1','X2'])
```

having two class and the data in non-linear. Now I want to convert this 2-d data into 3-D data space to draw the decision boundary between the classes. any one can help me

Comment: Reinventing SVM?

Comment: This ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51282146/5025009

Comment: Raj brother is there any way to find without using SVM?

Comment: @ZMKhattak Maybe you can manually try to find a new parameter(which is some combination of the original two), which can possibly seperate the data in 3d space.

Answer (score 0):

For converting this 2-D data into 3-D one you have to add another feature. This feature addition can be done in any of the following ways

1) Add extra features while creating random data by setting **n_features = 3**. This will add extra dimension at the time of creation. But it will be the addition of a new feature.

2) Another way is to create the third feature by applying arithmetic(like avg of 2 features etc) operation .